# How to fetch week of the month in django Template from datetime field?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have datetime field variable in Django template called dtv. So I use

dtv|date:'M'
To get the month of dtv value

dtv|date:'Y'
To get the year of the dtv value

so is there any way to get the week of the month. For example if dtv date is 2nd April 2015 I want to get week as 1st week

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a built in way to get the value you're looking for. You can however write your own [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/) that can get you the value you need. You can do some integer division to figure out the week number.

```
from __future__ import division # allows you to use // for floor division in python 2
import datetime                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

from django import template                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

register = template.Library()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

@register.simple_tag                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
def week_number(dt):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    """Takes a datetime object and returns the week of the month"""                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    return (dt.day - 1) // 7 + 1
```